# How to create a generated sequential number in a computed value in a select statement in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I would like to add a sequential number to a number as a computed column in a Select. I tried the below but SomeNumber = 50001 for both rows which means Row_Number seems to get reset to 1 for every row. I would like to generate a number and it increments for every row and add it to 50000 and get a unique SomeNumber value for every row. It needs to work in a view. No Sprocs. SQL Server 2008. I prefer to avoid using SQL Server's Sequence feature. The table already has a primary key and its values can't be used to add to 50000. 50000 is actually a computed number and there's a tiny chance it might overflow an Int if big numbers are added to it so therefore I would like to add 1, 2, 3, ... to it to lessen the chance of that happening.

```
CREATE TABLE example
( name VARCHAR(10),
  RN int)

INSERT INTO example
SELECT 'John', 1
UNION 
SELECT 'Jane', 1

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY RN ORDER BY RN) RowNumber,
(SELECT 50000 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY RN ORDER BY RN)) SomeNumber  <== value doesn't change
FROM example
```

Comment: Does it matter that the value isn't stable, i.e. as rows are inserted, updated and deleted the calculated value for `'John'` may change? Or may change without changes to the table data, e.g using `order by (select null)` which doesn't provide much of a guaranteed order?

Comment: It doesn't matter. The SomeNumber value is used as a temporary key to the UI. It doesn't care about the value. They just need to be unique. Also, I accepted @SteveC 's answer too soon. It's actually is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Edit] Based on the comments now there are 2 tables, #example and #other, which are related by the common column RN.  #other contains the SomeNumber integer column.  The query joins the table together on RN and adds a sequence number to the SomeNumber value for each RN.

```
drop table if exists #example;
go
CREATE TABLE #example
( name           VARCHAR(10),
  RN             int);

INSERT INTO #example
SELECT 'John', 1
UNION all
SELECT 'Jane', 1
UNION all
SELECT 'Jack', 2
UNION all
SELECT 'Jill', 2;

drop table if exists #other;
go
CREATE TABLE #other
( SomeNumber    int,
  RN            int);

INSERT INTO #other
SELECT 50000, 1
UNION 
SELECT 40000, 2;
```

Query

```
select e.*, oth.max_n+row_number() over (order by (select null)) seq_num
from #example e
     cross join (select max(o.SomeNumber) max_n from #other o) oth;
```

Output

```
name    RN  seq_num
John    1   50001
Jane    1   50002
Jack    2   50003
Jill    2   50004
```

Comment: Actually your answer is not the answer to my question and I am retracting my upvote. The unique number has to be the way I have it. It's still 50001 for all the rows.
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY RN ORDER BY RN) RowNumber,
(SELECT 50000 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) )  SomeNumber 
FROM example

Comment: Please provide the output you're looking for

Comment: 1, 50001
2, 50002

Using an inline  select as shown in my question

Comment: I was trying to simplify things. The actual query is something like this:
SELECT column1,
(SELECT MAX(somecolumn) + x FROM anothertable) from table. I want x to be an increasing number starting from 1.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work either. I don't have somenumber in a table. I need to find out what's the maximum somenumber from the other table and add to it a sequential number. That's why I have the inner select to find the max(somenumber).

Comment: Again please review